# Computing the kernel of an isogeny between two elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Consider the two rational elliptic curves -

$ E_{1}: y^{2}+y=x^{3}+x^{2}-131x-650 $ $ [\text{Cremona}:35a2] $

$ E_{2}: y^{2}+y=x^{3}+x^{2}-x $ $ [\text{Cremona}:35a3] $

We know that there is an isogeny of degree 9 between the above two curves. My question is how to write down the isogeny and compute it's kernel $?$

EDIT - Is there any theoretical way of calculating the kernel since I don't know how to find out the kernel from the kernel polynomial $?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). The code

> `E:=EllipticCurve("35a2");`
>
> `E2:=IsogenousCurves(E)[1];`
>
> `A,B:=IsIsogenous(E,E2);`
>
> `A;`
>
> `B;`

returns

> true
>
> Elliptic curve isogeny from: CrvEll: E to CrvEll: E2
>    taking (x : y : 1) to ((1/81*x^9 + 2/9*x^8 + 13*x^7 + 3392/27*x^6 - 30325/9*x^5
>       - 85999*x^4 - 24206654/27*x^3 - 50989888/9*x^2 - 199148981/9*x -
>       3252102320/81) / (x^8 + 134/3*x^7 + 4687/9*x^6 - 7022/3*x^5 - 655945/9*x^4 -
>       6723838/27*x^3 + 17079682/9*x^2 + 41442544/3*x + 1927297801/81) :
>       (1/729*x^12*y - 364/729*x^12 + 67/729*x^11*y - 24388/729*x^11 -
>       194/729*x^10*y - 557539/729*x^10 - 1985/243*x^9*y - 1017385/243*x^9 +
>       656695/729*x^8*y + 68692145/729*x^8 + 26025217/729*x^7*y +
>       1054678562/729*x^7 + 192550078/243*x^6*y + 544801208/243*x^6 +
>       8480552422/729*x^5*y - 57023892268/729*x^5 + 80725047070/729*x^4*y -
>       346491431755/729*x^4 + 475003324045/729*x^3*y + 525131058245/729*x^3 +
>       1557625275491/729*x^2*y + 11187520474201/729*x^2 + 2082152034392/729*x*y +
>       37883300781112/729*x - 467114355359/729*y + 1558207155673/27) / (x^12 +
>       67*x^11 + 4588/3*x^10 + 225865/27*x^9 - 187555*x^8 - 25720147/9*x^7 -
>       99672482/27*x^6 + 1512695518/9*x^5 + 28655848540/27*x^4 - 63917643605/81*x^3
>       - 771015395293/27*x^2 - 909684562072/9*x - 84610300761701/729) : 1)

and if you use now `Kernel(B)` then you get

> Subgroup scheme of E defined by x^4 + 67/3*x^3 + 11*x^2 - 1416*x - 43901/9

Comment: Here is the manual http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1379#15338

Comment: Thanks but how to compute the kernel of the isogeny from such a complicated expression ?

Comment: I just edited the answer. Use "Kernel".

Comment: But I am trying to write down the kernel in terms of $\mu_3$, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} $, $\mu_{3^2}$ where $\mu_3$ denotes the cubic roots of unity. Can you please help regarding that $?$

Comment: Can you check whether that quartic polynomial on $x$ is equal to the third division polynomial? If so, then the kernel would be exactly the 3-torsion (and isomorphic to $C_3\times C_3$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, the isogeny is of degree 9, and cyclic kernel (I know that because of the number of curves isogenous to E), so it is best to look at the 9th division polynomial.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have checked just now and the quartic polynomial on x is equal to the third division polynomial. But how do you say it is isomorphic to $C_3 * C_3$ $?$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sage code -                                E = EllipticCurve('35a2')
f = E.division_polynomial(3)
f

Comment: @Andrew: Aren't the zeros of the third division polynomial exactly the 3-torsion points (given that $3$ is a prime)? And over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero the $m$-torsion of any elliptic curve is isomorphic to $C_m\times C_m$?

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo How the number of curves isogenous to E related to cyclic kernel $?$

Comment: If the kernel was not cyclic, there would be 3 curves isogenous to $E$, different from $E$, of degrees 9, 3, and 3. But there is only one isogenous of degree 9, and one of degree 3. The isogeny described above is cyclic, of degree 9. The kernel is a cyclic subgroup of 9-torsion points. I am not sure why the Kernel command is giving the 3rd division polynomial.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo,@JyrkiLahtonen Sorry for the wrong computation. The quartic polynomial on x is not equal to the third division polynomial of 35a2 or 35a3.

Comment: That makes more sense... Calculate p(x), the 9th division polynomial instead, the polynomial that defines the kernel is probably a factor of p(x) instead.

Comment: 9 division polynomial of 35a2

Comment: Yes, the kernel is a subgroup of $E$, of 35a2.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo There is also another curve 35a1 in the same isogeny class. So if I consider 35a1 and 35a2, how to change the Magma code accordingly in order to derive the kernel polynomial for 35a1 and 35a2 ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Simply exchange the roles of E and E2, and 35a2 by 35a1 in the code above?